# Perl WWW::Mechanize set cookie stored to string

Tags: perl, http, cookies

i want to handle multible logins from my script, so im trying to save the actual cookies from [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) in a value (which works as expected), and use them again later, which wont work, heres my code:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => {} );
$agent->get('https://example.com/');

#save cookies to string
$cookies =  $agent->cookie_jar->as_string;
#clearing cookies
$agent->cookie_jar->clear;

#re-using the cookies (this wont work)
$agent->cookie_jar->load($cookies);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`HTTP::Cookies`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies):

```
   $cookie_jar->load
   $cookie_jar->load( $file )
       This method reads the cookies from the file and adds them to the $cookie_jar.  The file must be in the format written by the save() method.
```

You are using load with a string and not a file.
Because there is no reverse method to as_string you have to save and load, not as_string and load.
You might try to use just multiple cookie jars, e.g.

```
$old_cookies = $agent->cookie_jar;
$agent->cookie_jar({}); # new cookie jar
...
$agent->cookie_jar($old_cookies); # switch back to old cookie jar
```